# I have a table like this in sql

Tags: sql

I have table like dis

Tablename: adc

| Id | A | B | C | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 200 | 300 |  |
| 2 | 200 | 300 | 400 |  |
| 3 | 300 | 400 | 500 |  |

I want to add values of col a, b and c and input it into col total.

What should be the query? Columns a, b and c are `varchar` and total is `float`.

Comment: Why do you store numeric data (integers) in varchar columns?

Comment: What is the database platform?

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
UPDATE dbo.adc
SET Total = CAST(A as float) + CAST(B as float)+ CAST(C as float)
```

**On a side note:**

If there is not a specific requirement then you should try to alter the table column A,B and C as float or int as you are storing the same in it.

Comment: Varchar columns... You need to cast before adding. (Someone else downvotet.)

Comment: @jarlh:- Yes saw that. Updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @jarlh: Indeed. I did, since `select '1'+'1'+'1'` yield `111`. Now it should work in general (might be depending on the database platform).

Comment: That's very product specific behavior. (And no dbms specified here, so ANSI SQL is preferred.)

Comment: @anshulagarwal, did you mean you want to store the computed value? That's generally a bad idea, does often cause data inconsistency!

Answer (score 0):

use cast keyword like this :

```
select A, B, C, cast(A as float) + cast(B as float) + cast(C as float) as Total from adc;
```

Comment: what about datatypes ?

Comment: use cast keyword like this : select A, B, C, cast(A as float) + cast(B as float) + cast(C as float) as Total from adc;

Comment: so may be you can add it to your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the sum of a, b, and c:

```
select a, b, c, cast(a as float) + cast(b as float) + cast(c as float)
from adc
```